# Beagle Bone serial communication

Tags: serial-port, beagleboard, uart

I am working on Beagle Bone Rev A5 and my UART1 and UART2 are working fine with these mux settings:

```
echo 20 > /sys/kernel/debug/omap_mux/uart1_rxd
echo 0 > /sys/kernel/debug/omap_mux/uart1_txd
echo 1 > /sys/kernel/debug/omap_mux/spi0_d0
echo 21 > /sys/kernel/debug/omap_mux/spi0_sclk
```

Now I want hardware flow control enabled and for that I want to use UART4 and UART5. Can anybody help me enabling `Rx`,`Tx`,`RTS`,`CTS` of `UART 4` & `5`? What will be the `mux` setting for these `UART`s?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This page helped me a bit:
  http://www.jerome-bernard.com/blog/2012/06/04/beaglebone-serial-ports-and-xbees/

You have to set :

- UART4 - RX    /sys/kernel/debug/omap_mux/gpmc_wait0   26  Mode 6 - Input
- UART4 - TX    /sys/kernel/debug/omap_mux/gpmc_wpn     6   Mode 6 - Output
- UART5 - RX    /sys/kernel/debug/omap_mux/lcd_data9    24  Mode 4 - Input
- UART5 - TX    /sys/kernel/debug/omap_mux/lcd_data8    4   Mode 4 - Output